# Query publicly available full nodes

Tags: bitcoin-core, json-rpc, full-node, spv

I don't want to run a full node yet, but I want to build an application. How and what do I use to query publicly available nodes? What nodes besides blockchain.info are publicly available for me to query over HTTP/HTTPS?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you want to do there are several answers.

Top 2:

- https://longhorn.bullpay.com - Up to 2,000 Tx's returned per call
- https://live.blockcypher.com/btc/ - Up to 2,000 Tx's returned per call

These may work for you but have reduced thru put:

- https://blockexplorer.com - Up to 50 Tx's returned per call
- https://blockchain.info - Up to 50 Tx's returned per call

All these services act like a full node (at least bullpay and blockcypher have the ability to send transactions, i'm unsure about the other two in this regard). They all have free versions. Some have paid versions to increase the number of requests you can make per second for increased scalability. The links are to their explorers. API documentation can be found on each site.

So again, it depends on what you're trying to accomplish. If you're working heavily with historical data for things like auditing, you'll want to obtain more data faster. Focus on the first two. If you're just messing around then any of them would work with varying degree's of effort.

Answer (score -1):

Then you can go for an api provider. There are plenty them are available out there. https://applikeysolutions.com/blog/10-best-blockchain-api-providers-for-developers

Comment: This article is nonsense for an answer. Neurowave, Tierion, Factom Alpha, Coinbase wouldn't have any benefit to the question posed in the context of "not running a full node locally". Bitcore would be a full node he'd have to run.  Colu is out of business but still wouldn't replace a "full node". Gem, looks like an asset management system.  Chromaway is a new blockchain called Postchain. There are 2 or 3 good ones which i'll break out and add to an actual answer. The author of the provided took the term "blockchain API" and just googled it.